# how to avoid UI blocking in a VisualStudio Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I have a VisualStudio Add-in (plug-in), when the function of this Add-in is triggered, it will take a few seconds to finish. During this period, the UI is blocked. How can I avoid blocking the UI?

Comment: Is this an add-in you wrote or maintain the code for?  Or is it a 3rd-party add-in?

Comment: This is a add-in that I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

Do the actual work in a thread such as a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  This will keep the UI thread responsive since it isn't handling the expensive operation.